# Debian update fails with "Raid version incompatible"

Tags: debian, raid

While installing proftpd, it dropped with following error:

```
[....] Starting ftp server: proftpdhexadecacordis proftpd[26849]: mod_tls_memcache/0.1: notice: unable to register 'memcache' SSL session cache: Memcache support not enabled
. ok 
Setting up proftpd-mod-vroot (0.9.2-2+b2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I first did not notice `linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64` error, so I tried to set up libmemcache, and it dropped with same error.

So, I ran an upgrade, and everything updated, except following. So I ran it again, to display clear view of error:

```
# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  xserver-xorg-input-all
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64 (3.2.46-1+deb7u1) ...
Running depmod.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.2.0-4-amd64 /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-amd64
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.2.0-4-amd64 /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-runlilo 3.2.0-4-amd64 /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64
Warning: LBA32 addressing assumed
Fatal: Incompatible Raid version information on /dev/md0   (RV=0.90 GAI=1.2)
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-runlilo exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64.postinst line 696.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I can't find any solution connected with "Incompatible Raid version information".

Please, explain me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Actually, there are quite a few Google hits when searching "Fatal: Incompatible Raid version information on /dev/md0" . It seems you're using lilo as a bootloader (any special reason?) and your problem is soft RAID + lilo - specific. If you want to continue using lilo, please paste the output of `# mdadm -E /dev/md0` and we'll take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are using LILO to boot, and it does not understand the new mdadm metadata format.  You should switch to grub2 instead.